# remove console.log on assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

During assets:precompile the javascript is minified, but console.logs are left in.

is there a way to remove all console.logs on precompile when the code is pushed to production?

Comment: Interesting!  I imagine this wouldn't be too difficult to implement with a `gsub`, but rails never fails to amaze me with useful stuff like this already built in.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of Uglifier 2.4.0 the :compress option includes support for :drop_console which means you can easily remove all console.* functions using something like this in your config/environments/production.rb file:

```
# Compress JavaScripts
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(
  # Remove all console.* functions
  :compress => { :drop_console => true }
) if defined? Uglifier
```

Comment: What about `for( i=0; i<10; i++ ){ console.log( "i = " + i ) }` ? Does it return an empty loop?

Comment: Ivan Black, yes, or better: `u = Uglifier.new(compress: {drop_console: true})`; `u.compress 'for( i=0; i<10; i++ ){ console.log( "i = " + i ) }'` will give you: `"for(i=0;10>i;i++);"`

Answer (score 5):

You could add this to `application.js.erb`. This solution would prevent any logging to `console.log()` in production environment, period. But it will still allow logging to `console.error()`.

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  window.console = {};
  window.console.log = function(){};
<% else %>
  // the || in the code ensures IE compatability
  window.console = window.console || {};
  window.console.log = window.console.log || function(){};
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To point you in the right direction, check out the **[Use as a code pre-processor](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#use-as-a-code-pre-processor)** section of **[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)**.

I need to research more about how to pass a `--define DEVMODE=false` flag within the `rake assets:precompile`, but adjusting your code to wrap `console.log` in with the `DEVMODE` boolean as described in the link above should get you the result you're looking for.

**Update:**

In some file that will load during `rake assets:precompile`, add the following monkey patch.

```
class Uglifier
  private
    def mangle_options
      {
        "mangle" => @options[:mangle],
        "toplevel" => @options[:toplevel],
        "defines" => { DEVMODE: ["name", "null"] }, # This line sets DEVMODE
        "except" => @options[:except],
        "no_functions" => @options[:mangle] == :vars
      }
    end
end
```

As I mentioned in a comment below, Uglifier **[does not support passing a `:defines` mangle option](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/lib/uglifier.rb#L109)**. You could optionally change the marked line above to `"defines" => @options[:defines]` and update your config with this line

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(defines: { DEVMODE: ["name", "null"] })
```

When running the rake task, `DEVMODE` will now be converted to `null` in your source. Now, given the following code in your Javascript source:

```
if (typeof DEVMODE === 'undefined') {
  DEVMODE = true;
}

if (DEVMODE) {
  console.log('some log message');
}
```

By default *(in development mode)*, `DEVMODE` will be set to `true`, causing the `console.log()` to execute. When `rake assets:precompile` is run, UglifyJS is going to set `DEVMODE` to `null` before compilation/compression begins. When walking over `if (null) {` it will see that the condition will never evaluate `true`, and will strip this dead code from the resulting source.

As long as you write your `console.log()` calls like above or shorthand as

```
DEVMODE && console.log('some log message');
```

the `console.log()` calls will be stripped from the production code. I can see other benefits to this too outside of stripping `console.log()`, allowing for other development-specific code to coexist with other Javascript in development mode **and only** development mode.

Comment: How can I add this to the assets pipeline?

Comment: I'm researching that *(never done it myself)*, but it may require some monkey patching, as Uglifier **[does not accept a `:defines` option](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/lib/uglifier.rb#L109)**.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me - Uglify didn't eliminate the dead code. So I did: `if <%= Rails.env.production? ? 'null' : 'true' %>` then it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Uglify seems to be picky about `false` values it will recognize as wrapping dead code. I'm not surprised (after my testing for this answer) you needed to tweak it a bit for your application.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention the solution of [bitcrowd](http://blog.bitcrowd.net/disable-console-log-in-production/). Their idea basically is:

1. define a `data` attribute in your body tag that represents the state of your app (development/production/...) - e.g. `<body data-env="<%= Rails.env %>">`
2. depending on this let `console.log()` print something out or do nothing at all - e.g.:

   ```
   if ($('body').data('env') == 'production' || typeof console == "undefined"){
       var console = { log: function() {}, debug: function() {}, info: function() {} };
   }
   ```

Comment: This is fine if you're not using tools that let you drop the code altogether, but generally it's better to not output the code at all.